# HTML form doesn't work with PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

If I make `insert_teacher('bla bla','bla bla','dqsd')` in PHP file, but when I want to make it with HTML form it doesn't show me anything, and nothing is inserted in my DB.

```
<?php
  include_once("resources/functions.php");
echo 1;
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      $name=$_POST['name'];
      $exp=$_POST['exp'];
      $sub=$_POST['sub'];

         $insert=insert_teacher($name,$exp,'dqsd');// return 1 or 0
          echo $insert;



  }

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>

<ul class="sidenav">
  <li><a  href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="setup_teachers.php">Teachers Section</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
<h3 class="warning"><?php if(isset($b)) echo $b; ?></h3> 
<h3>Adding teachers information</h3>

<div>
  <form action="" method="POST" >
    <label for="fname">FullName</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="name">

    <label for="lname">Experience</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="exp">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <select id="country" name="sub">
      <option value="physics">physique</option>
      <option value="maths">mathematique</option>
      <option value="english">Anglais</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We probably don't know what `insert_teacher()` is. By the way, learn AJAX.

Comment: Why'd you copy and paste the same text 3 times??

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Kids shouldnt play with databases, yet alone code in general.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Where do you see issues with quoting in the question?

Comment: @Barmar `insert_teacher($name,$exp,'dqsd')` it's just a hunch/lucky guess (which I stand at being 50% right and/or 50% wrong) ;-) You can take a stab at putting in your own answer or duplicate, or just close it as unclear/why not working, or a custom message like: *"I'm voting to close this question because the OP doesn't understand the first thing about using code"*. The ball is in your court, *as it were*. ;-)

Comment: I voted to close because he didn't provide the appropriate code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't provide the appropriate code.

Comment: ^ there you go ;-) it's a valid vote.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong here but I'll try help anyway.

First your submit should have a name. Eg

```
<input type="submit" name="insertx"/>
```

Second, you call the filled form with the submit button's name. Eg

```
if(isset($_POST['insertx'])){

//your code

}
```

Third, read on how insert in php in `PDO` or `mysqli` unless you want to get hacked!
(NB:`mysqli_real_escape_string`)

There's a lot to learn, but its not rock hard.
All the best

Answer (score 0):

you have to add name to the submit tag:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```